# Using file name in json parsing (Haskell Aeson)

Tags: haskell, aeson

I have no experience in Haskell. I'm trying to parse many `.json` files to a data structure in Haskell using [aeson](https://github.com/bos/aeson). However, by reasons beyond my control, I need to store the name of the file from where the data was parsed as one of the fields in my data. A simple example of what I have so far is:

```
data Observation = Observation { id :: Integer
                               , value :: Integer
                               , filename :: String}

instance FromJSON Observation where
  parseJson (Object v) =
    Observation <$> (read <$> v .: "id")
                <*> v .: "value"
                <*> ????
```

My question is: what is a smart way to be able to serialize my data when parsing a json file having access to the name of the file?

What comes in my mind is to define another `data` like `NotNamedObservation`, initialize it and then having a function that converts `NotNamedObservation -> String -> Observation` (where String is the filename) but that sounds like a very poor approach.

Thanks.

Comment: I think your idea of defining an extra datatype representing an "observation without a filename" is a very good one!

Comment: It may not seem terribly clever, but I also think your suggested solution is the best one. Particularly if it had the signature `NotNamedObservation -> FilePath -> Observation`, then it's obvious what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make your instance a function from file path to Observation:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS
import System.Environment

data Observation = Observation { ident    :: Integer
                               , value    :: Integer
                               , filename :: FilePath
                               } deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON (FilePath -> Observation) where
  parseJSON (Object v) =
    do i <- read <$> v .: "id"
       l <- v .: "value"
       pure $ Observation i l

main :: IO ()
main = do
  files <- getArgs
  fileContents <- traverse LBS.readFile files
  print fileContents
  let fs = map (maybe (error "Invalid json") id . decode) fileContents
      jsons :: [Observation]
      jsons = zipWith ($) fs files
  print jsons
```

Answer (score 2):

When you don't control the `data` definition and you have strict requirements about the format to parse, it's better to write the (de)serializer explicitly.

If external information is required to fully construct values, avoid the `FromJSON`/`ToJSON` type classes, and just write standalone parsers.

*aeson*'s deriving mechanism is more suited to applications that talk to themselves (and thus only care about round-tripping between `parseJSON` and `toJSON`), or where there is flexibility either in defining the JSON format or the Haskell types.

---

If you still have to use these classes for some reason, one option is of course to just put `undefined` in those missing fields. To rely on the type system more, you can also parameterize types by a "phase" (that assumes again you can tweak the data type), which is a type constructor that wraps some fields.

- [Functor functors](https://www.benjamin.pizza/posts/2017-12-15-functor-functors.html)
- One way to keep that style compatible with regular records is to use [this HKD/defunctionalization design pattern](http://reasonablypolymorphic.com/blog/higher-kinded-data).

---

```
data Observation' p = Observation
  { id :: Integer
  , value :: Integer
  , filename :: p String }

-- This is isomorphic to the original Observation data type
type Observation = Observation Identity

-- When we don't have the filename available, we keep the field empty with Proxy
instance FromJSON (Observation' Proxy) where
  ...

mkObservation :: FileName -> Observation' Proxy -> Observation
```

Comment: This would be a strong answer for someone with more haskell experience, but I think you're turning the fire hose onto a newbie here. The article from Sandy Maguire is great though, so thank you for that.